# In Eclipse, How to sort methods by class during auto-complete?

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, keyboard-shortcuts

In Eclipse, you can press period after an object to see its methods and the methods it inherited from its super-classes. Is there a way, (keyboard shortcut during auto-complete or otherwise) that allows you to organize the methods by class, (this, super, super's super)? This would help find methods specific to this subclass much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible :(

Answer (score 0):

Not that i know.

Go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist.

There you should see an option "Sort proposals" where the only options are "by relevance" and "alphabetically".

You may use the Type Hierarchy. Not a real solution to what you'd like to have but the closest approach I could tell.